# date time problem with codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have set mysql  database field type as 'datetime'

when i send

```
$now = time();
echo form_hidden('a_date', unix_to_human($now));
```

from views all I get in database is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

please help

Answer (score 1):

i usually do it like this

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
echo form_hidden('a_date', $now);
```

If you want to output differently, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Also, if you want to record the time and not update it, I would recommend a timestamp field instead of datetime field. That way, you don't have to pass the db anything